# Process file contents with gnu-parallel

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I have a file with contents as follows:

```
/path/to/file1
/path/to/file2
/path/to/file3
/path/to/file4
```

I want to run a command on each line in parallel using the `gnu-parallel` utility which I'm aware supports file inputs using `::::`. What I'm unsure about is that which arguments should I pass to gnu-parallel to split the file contents by `\n` and process in parallel?

Comment: See chapter 2: https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's `man parallel`:

```
NAME
       parallel - build and execute shell command lines from
       standard input in parallel

SYNOPSIS
       parallel [options] [command [arguments]] < list_of_arguments
       [...]
```

Here's an example of this form of invocation:

```
$ cat mylist.txt
/path/to/file1
/path/to/file2
/path/to/file3
/path/to/file4

$ parallel 'echo "I am processing:" {}' < mylist.txt
I am processing: /path/to/file1
I am processing: /path/to/file2
I am processing: /path/to/file3
I am processing: /path/to/file4
```